# Htaccess 301 redirect appending variables at end of query

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect some existing mod_rewrite queries to their better counterpart, but running into an issue where it appends the page's variables to the end of the URL.

For example,

```
/garden/garden-benches/cat_199.html
```

Is becoming:

```
/garden-furniture/patio-furniture/garden-benches-garden-seats/cat_199.html?_a=viewCat&catId=199
```

I just don't want those variables at the end.

The code is:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /garden/garden-benches/cat_199.html http://www.sustainable-furniture.co.uk   /garden-furniture/patio-furniture/garden-benches-garden-seats/cat_199.html
```

The rest of the .htaccess file - which is creating the urls in the first place.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)$
RewriteRule cat_([0-9]+)(\.[a-z]{3,4})?(.*)$    index.php?_a=viewCat&catId=$1&%1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)$
RewriteRule prod_([0-9]+)(\.[a-z]{3,4})?$   index.php?_a=viewProd&productId=$1&%1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)$
RewriteRule info_([0-9]+)(\.[a-z]{3,4})?$   index.php?_a=viewDoc&docId=$1&%1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)$
RewriteRule tell_([0-9]+)(\.[a-z]{3,4})?$   index.php?_a=tellafriend&productId=$1&%1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)$
RewriteRule _saleItems(\.[a-z]+)?(\?.*)?$   index.php?_a=viewCat&catId=saleItems&%1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrites and redirects are two different things. However, you can still redirect using a rewrite, by flagging the rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^garden/garden-benches/cat_199\.html$ garden-furniture/patio-furniture/garden-benches-garden-seats/cat_199.html [R=301,L]
```

**Edit 1** - I have removed the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` condition. Perhaps it skipped it because `.html` files are files, and would be not be filtered through the rule.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I had tried rewrites as well, very similar to your code. Ive just given it a go and it doesn't work, it doesn't even attempt to redirect to the newer page?

Comment: Try to remove the leading slash from the regex. `^garden/garden-benches/cat_199\.html$`. The `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` seems redundant because the URL `/garden/garden-benches/cat_199.html` should never match a directory

Comment: Ive removed the leading slash and dropped the !-d separately. Neither have changed. Is this because its not a real directory and just a mod_rewrite url?

Comment: The `!-d` can stay, but the `!-f` should be dropped.

Comment: Still not redirecting... I'm glad I'm not going crazy in this - this is what I previously tried

Comment: What is the complete URL? You may obfuscate the domain name if you wish. Another thought is that *something* seems to append query parameters to your URLs (*/garden-furniture/patio-furniture/garden-benches-garden-seats/cat_199.html?_a=viewCat&catId=199*), perhaps some other `.htaccess` or redirect mechanics are interfering?

Comment: Updating the main post now to have the rest of the htaccess file in.

Comment: Change your rewrite conditions from *RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.\*)$* to **RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)$**. As of now your conditions are not doing anything as the star repeater matches **0 or more** repetitions of **any** characters. This in turn causes the first RewriteRule to be triggered and appends the cat query parameters

Comment: Just changed, that breaks all of the existing already working urls with 404 errors. Hmm

Comment: Hm well yes, in your case the rewrite condition should only be applied on rules where you actually use the query string.. I would suggest removing the conditions all together if you're not using it for anything. Then move the rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^garden/garden-benches/cat_199\.html$ /garden-furniture/patio-furniture/garden-benches-garden-seats/cat_199.html [R=301,L]` ABOVE the first RewriteRule but you'll still have a problem because the new redirect URL will still match the `cat_..` RewriteRule and append new query parameters. Phew. It's a bit much for a comment, I'll have a think

Comment: Actually, I might be mistaken. You don't seem to use the `[R]` flag in your rewrites so theoretically the query parameters shouldn't be appended to the URL.

Comment: Are you sure it's not your application that does it?

Comment: Incredibly removing the condition, as you suggested earlier has allowed it to work! - It now redirects there straight away